# How to identify crontab child job?

Tags: linux, unix

My unix production server has test.ksh files, but every day it's running on daily basics using job.
I want to know which crontab job is calling this script. I checked usign below command, but i didn't find exact job name,

1. crontab -l
   --It has been listed 100 job --
   I have analysed above mentioned 100 job, but i didn't get test.ksh file
2. crontab -l | grep "test.ksh"
   --file not found

But the file available in one directory, I can't find which job is called test.ksh script.

Finding:
1. Whether it's child job? - If yes, how can i identify the child job?

Answer (score 1):

you could use `pstree -p xxxx` where `xxxx` is the pid of `crond`. You will then get a nice hierarchical overview of all offspring processes of `crond`.

Comment: this actually helped me on CentOS 7. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a child script, use `ps -ef` and use the ppid of the test.ksh job to identify the calling script.

For example, consider these two scripts, the first just calls the second

**parent**

```
#! /bin/sh
# Run child process
./child
```

**child**

```
#! /bin/sh
sleep 60
```

`ps -ef` shows (with a lot of other processes removed)

```
UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
501  5725  5724   0  8:22pm ttys000    0:00.28 -bash
501  6046  5725   0 11:38am ttys000    0:00.01 /bin/sh ./parent
501  6047  6046   0 11:38am ttys000    0:00.00 /bin/sh ./child
501  6048  6047   0 11:38am ttys000    0:00.00 sleep 60
```

The pid is the process identifier, so child has process id 6047.  Its ppid - 6046 - is the process id of its parent as you can see looking at the entry for the parent process.